# Informatica cloud intelligent structure model performance tuning

Tags: informatica, iics-di

I'm facing performance bottleneck with intelligent structure model in IICS where source is json and target is parquet.

Json file is having multiple nested groups or hierarchies to read 239 fields in side. But if I pass 67 fields completed in seconds even though 200 files at a time. But today I tested with 239 fields and only 1 file taking longer.

I've applied all possible advance properties in source & target but still parsing is taking more than 2 hours and still running.

Please suggest any tuning option to complete in minutes

**Note**: mapping is in advanced mode.